# jQuery - best way to present huge amount of scrollable data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array with length of 1.5k, each entry needs to be shown (set of DIV's per entry) but when I'm showing it all at once the browser hangs most of the time. I'm trying to figure out the most flexible, easiest and user friendly way to present this data. All my ideas were hard to make or not user friendly. What I've thought of so far:

- show the DIV's that are in user's viewport (hard to make it work on all screen configurations)
- group the entries by pages and switch them on scroll event (not user friendly - no visible scrollbar)
- load more entries when "Load more" is pressed (not user friendly, user would have to click 100 times on the button if he'd like to get to the 1000th entry, and it would hang the browser anyway)

What is the best way to present this data?

Comment: you need to work in batches, and use some sort of infinite-scroll mechanism to render to the screen each batch from the total items.

Comment: Try the User Experience Stack Exchange: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @vsync, I know that I should do it in parts but I have no idea how to implement this in jQuery.

Comment: well then...since you want to program things that are not in your power to do at the moment...and I can't think of a script that does all out-of-the-box...you should first become proficient well enough in javascript I guess, because this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Update - I've also wrote another lib:
https://github.com/yairEO/infinite

Using this [endless scrolling](https://github.com/yairEO/endless) script, you could do:

```
var items      = [], // array of objects to load on scroll
    batchCount = 10;

// load more items
function showMore(howMany){
    // remove X amount of items from the total hidden item's jQuery object and show them
    var toLoad = items.splice(0, howMany), // from the items array, cut only the batch we need to show
        i;

    // Make sure that an image in the current batch is loaded before adding it to the DOM
    for( i=toLoad.length; i--; ){
        // show item toLoad[i] 
        batchCount--;
    }
}
    
function onScrollEnd(){
    if( batchCount <= 0 && items.length ){
        // load 10 items on every scroll
        batchCount = 10;
        showMore(batchCount);
    }
}

$(window).endless({offset:'20%', callback: onScrollEnd });
```

Your `items` array could be a javascript array of DOM elements or a jQuery st of elements, which you should [convert](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to a real array for this example code to work without much changes.